# Windows Azure Ubuntu - 500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd error while making an FTP connection

Tags: ubuntu, azure, ftp

I have created a VM on Windows Azure and running Ubuntu on that
I have been able to successfully communicate using the http protocol on port 80

However, I am not able to make a successful FTP connection.
Here is what I have done so far

- Created an End Point with both public and private port as 21
- Installed vsftp on the server
- Made the config changes in vsftpd.conf; `local_enable=YES, write_enable=YES`

Now when I try to make a normal FTP connection on Filezilla, I have and error which says`500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd`

Can someone please let me know what I am missing

Help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Same happens with Amazon EC2

Answer (score 11):

The following may help:

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

Answer (score 5):

As reto suggested, adding:

`seccomp_sandbox=NO`

To your vsftpd.conf file (usually located in /etc) should fix this problem (make sure you "sudo service vsftpd restart" afterwards).

VSFTPD uses kernel module seccomp in a way that produces this bug on certain kernels. See this post for more info: http://chemdroid.net/en/ubuntu/23-vsftpd-500-oops-priv-sock-get-cmd.

I wanted to add this detail to reto's post, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet...